# Constraining jsdoc/typescript type to an array member

Tags: typescript, jsdoc

I'm using typescript in jsdoc, and am trying to constrain a variable to one of a known set of values that I have in an array.

I know I can do it like this:

```js
/** @type {'one'|'two'|'three'} */
let v = 'four';
// ==> Error, type 'four' is not assignable to type 'one'|'two'|'three'
```

In my case, I have the desired values nearby in an array. To avoid retyping, I'd like to somehow reference them, but I don't know if it's possible. I'd like something like this:

```js
const OPTIONS = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

/** @type {string<Options>} */
let v = 'four';
// ==> Desired -- Error, type 'four' is not assignable to type 'one'|'two'|'three'
// ==> but that doesn't actually work...
```

Is there some way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [Augusts 28, 2021](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/45464), It's possible using JSDoc inline `@type {const}` like following:

```js
const OPTIONS = /** @type {const} */ (['one', 'two', 'three']);

/** @type {typeof OPTIONS[number]} */
let v = 'four'; 
//  ^ error: Type '"four"' is not assignable to type '"one" | "two" | "three" |
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can achieve that with an array, as they are mutable in runtime:

```
const OPTIONS = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
OPTIONS[0] = 'BOOM';
```

You can, however, change an array to a tuple (tuples are immutable):

```
const OPTIONS = ['one', 'two', 'three'];                
const OPTIONS_TUPLE = ['one', 'two', 'three'] as const;
```

Compare inferred types:

```
// const OPTIONS: string[]
// const OPTIONS_TUPLE: readonly ["one", "two", "three"]
```

Now, you can retrieve the type you want:

```
const OPTIONS_TUPLE = ['one', 'two', 'three'] as const;
type OptionsValue = typeof OPTIONS_TUPLE[number];
const x: OptionsValue = 'four'; 
//TS2322: Type '"four"' is not assignable to type '"one" | "two" | "three"'.
```

Comment: Thanks, really helpful.  Unfortunately it looks like `as const` is not currently available in jsdoc syntax, but i'll keep an eye on this for down the road. https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30445

Leaving question open for a while in case there are other suggestions that are currently possible.